# Bootstrap Sidebar WIdth

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap. Trying to get around sidebar which is having 300px of width. Currently using span3 I'll get 270px & using span4 I'll get 370px.

Is there a way where I could get 300px of sidebar, if not I'll have to stick to span3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use grids. Begin by referring the [manual](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Here is a simple layout. Assuming you are using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">Main Contents Here</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Sidebar Widget Here</div>
</div>
```

This creates a two column layout.

Comment: Thanks aliasm2k. Yes, that's what I am doing. But I want to know if there is a way to make the sidebar width to 300px, as span3 would make it 270px & span4 would make it 370.

Comment: Bootstrap measures using grid units. A total of 12 grid units are available, which you can divide as per your requirement. If you need a wider content area and smaller sidebar, you may try 10-2 combination that the 8-4 combination in the example.

Comment: This will give me the sidebar to be of 270px. Where my question was how can I have a Sidebar with 300px of width. 

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">Contents Area</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Sidebar</div>
</div>`

Similarly if I do it with col-lg-8 (Contents) & col-lg-4 (Sidebar) I'll get my sidebar of 370px width.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create two new col-md's for your specific requirements.

Then add them to all the media queries for complete responsiveness.